# How to change axis labels using with visreg along with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visreg

I'm using the `visreg` package with `gg = TRUE` (so it'll use `ggplot2` graphics) to render my fitted model plots.

It automatically uses the names of the independent variable factors as the x axis labels, but I need them to appear slightly differently and tried to change the labels text using `scale_x_discrete` as can be seen [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-ticks-a-guide-to-customize-tick-marks-and-labels).

But when I do so, the x axis labels, the axis line and its title become blank. 
I believe I'm failing to map the `labels` parameter to the `breaks` parameter.

I also get the message

> Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.

The problem probably lies within how `visreg` stores the variables (and its levels) information. When using `ggplot2` alone, this information can be easily recovered from the used dataset using `data$variablename`. But by creating the basic plot through `visreg` this is not so straightforward.

What I've already tried:

- Using the variable's levels' names as plotted by default as the breaks.
- Trying to access the variable levels with `fit$xlevels$Species`.
- Guessing `visreg` could be ascribing integers as the levels and trying to use
  `breaks = c(as.factor("1","2","3"))`.

How to reproduce the problem:

```
library(visreg)
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)

visreg(fit, gg = T) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
                   labels = c("SETOSA", "VERSICOLOR", "VIRGINICA"))

# ----------------------- OR the equivalent: 

visreg(fit, gg = T) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("setosa" = "SETOSA",
"versicolor" = "VERSICOLOR", "virginica" = "VIRGINICA"))
```

How the x axis looks without trying to change the labels:

```
library(visreg)
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)

visreg(fit, gg = T) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest this simple solution:

```
library(visreg)
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)
iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species, labels=c("SETOSA", "VERSICOLOR", "VIRGINICA"))

fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
visreg(fit, gg = T)
```

[image]